# insertar datos en mysql con php con la relacion muchos es a muchos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7

Tengo una base de datos con una relación muchos es a muchos, donde los productos pueden tener muchas categorías y los categorías pueden tener muchos productos, como es una relación mucho a muchos tengo una tabla intermediaria que contiene dos campos que serían el idProducto de la tabla producto y el idCategoria de la tabla categoría, en mi archivo php me cree un formulario donde ingreso un producto, y también unos chexbox donde me traigo todas las categorías que tengo en mi base de datos, para que cuando esté creando mi producto seleccione a través de los chexbox a todas las categorías a las que este producto podrá pertenecer, tengo un total de 5 categorías en los chexbox, ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo hacer mi consulta hacia la base de datos para ingresar el producto con sus respectivas categorías a la tabla intermediaria? Además tener en cuenta que por ejemplo estoy ingresando un producto, quizás ese producto solamente pertenezca a tres de las 5 categorías que me estoy trayendo de la base de datos y estoy mostrando a través de chexbox o quizás otro producto pertenezca a 2 de las 5 categorías que estoy mostrando, entonces como podría hacer mi sentencia sql para poder insertar estos datos!? Hasta el momento he podido realizar todo lo que he dicho a excepción de insertar finalmente en la Base de Datos ya que no estoy obteniendo el id del producto.
Adjunto el código que he realizado hasta el momento, la cual no se si la manera en la que lo estoy haciendo hasta el momento es la mas optima.

Ingreso el código del formulario:

```html
<?php

    require("conexion.php"); 
    //Consulta Hacia la BD para traerme todas las categorias que tengo en la tabla categoria 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias"; 
    $query = $conexion->query($sql); 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Creo el formulario donde voy a registrar un nuevo producto y a la vez le voy a asignar las categorias a las 
         que va a pertenecer este producto -->
    <form action="app.php" method="post">

        <!-- Ingreso el nombre del producto a registar -->
        <input type="text" name="txtProducto" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre"><br><br>

        <!-- Luego, mediante la consulta hacia la Base de datos me traigo todas la categorias y las imprimo en formato de checkbox  -->
        <?php

            if($query){
                if($query->num_rows>0){
                    while($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>

        <!-- Una vez que logro traerme e imprimir las categorias en formato checkbox, eligo las categorias a las que va a pertenecer el 
             producto que ingrese en el input anterior -->
        <?php echo $fila["nombre"]?><input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="<?php echo $fila["id"] ?>"><br>

        <?php

                    }
                }
            }

        ?>
            <br>

            <!-- Envio los datos para poder insertarlos en la BD  -->
            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">

        </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Ingreso el código donde estoy insertando el producto junto con sus respectivas categorías en la Base de Datos, en la cual al final no estoy obteniendo el id del producto:

```
<?php

require("conexion.php"); 

//Recibo los datos mediante POST 
$nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"]; 
$categoria = $_POST["categoria"];

//Inserto el producto en la tabla productos primero, ya que como tengo una relacion mucho a muchos, primero tengo que tener el producto 
//registrado para poder llenar la tabla intermidiaria entre productos y categorias a travez de la clave foranea(FK). 
$sql = "INSERT INTO productos (id, producto) VALUES (NULL, $nombre)";
$query = $conexion->query($sql); 

//Compruebo que la query se ejecute correctamente 
if($query){
    echo "Producto Ingresado correctamente";
} 

//Ahora recien empiezo a insertar los datos en la tabla productos_categorias que corresponde a la tabla que va a manejar la 
//relacion mucho a muchos entre los productos y categorias
//A travez del foraech voy recorriendo la variable categoria, que contiene todas las categorias que seleccione en el formulario anterior
foreach($categoria as $valor){
    //Voy insertando los datos en la tabla productos_categorias a travez de los id de categoria, pero el problema es 
    //que no tengo el id del producto que acabo de registrar, por lo cual no puedo ir llenando la tabla debido a que me falta el id 
    //de este producto 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO productos_categorias (idProducto, idCategoria) VALUES ($meFaltaElIdDelProducto,$valor)"; 
} 
?>
```

También Adjunto la imagen del modelo de mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta función después de hacer el insert a la tabla productos.
$UltimoId = **mysqli_insert_id();** para obtener el id de producto y luego al insertar en la tabla productos_categorias asignas al idproducto $lastid

asi:
**$sql = "INSERT INTO productos_categorias (idProducto, idCategoria) VALUES ($UltimoId ,$valor)";**

Solo funcionará si el id de la tabla productos es auto_increment.

Saludos